# Google Authentication - Owin - Non MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net, owin

Is there any helpful link to implement Google Authentication - Owin in a Non MVC Web Application using Asp.net

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is helpful, as it gives a good explanation 
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application

Comment: This is for MVC. I am looking for a non-mvc project with no controller.